# How to consolidate if statements used to search around a cell in a 2D space

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement

Here is a section of `code`:

```
 if (y[X][Y] == 'B')
        {
            System.out.printf("      (%2d,%2d)         %3d\n", X, Y, digCount);
            boneFound = true;
        }
        else
        if (y[X][Y + 1] == 'B')
        {
            System.out.printf("      (%2d,%2d)         %3d\n", X, Y + 1, digCount);
            boneFound = true;
        }
        else
        if (y[X][Y - 1] == 'B')
        {
            System.out.printf("      (%2d,%2d)         %3d\n", X, Y - 1, digCount);
            boneFound = true;
        }
        else
        if (y[X - 1][Y] == 'B')
        {
            System.out.printf("      (%2d,%2d)         %3d\n", X - 1, Y, digCount);
            boneFound = true;
        }
        else
        if (y[X + 1][Y] == 'B')
        {
            System.out.printf("      (%2d,%2d)         %3d\n", X + 1, Y, digCount);
            boneFound = true;
```

I want to search an `index` of a `double array` as well as each `index` that is one space up, down, left, and right. Then I want to `print` the `index` of the `array` that has the character 'B'. Is there a more effective way of doing this without all of these `if`-statements ?

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with these if statements. They make sense. Just improve the indentation and format and it will be a lot more readable.

Comment: You could use a loo;, || (or) in single if statement; case statements

Comment: Do you really want to find only if a B is present? Or do yo want to report all the nearby Bs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make use of the short circuit `||` and group all the repeated code into a function. This wil get you started:

```
boneFound = at(X,Y) || at(X,Y+1) || at(X,Y-1) || at(X-1,Y) || at(X+1,Y);
```

Your `at` method can be something like:

```
private static boolean at(X, Y) {
   boolean boneHere = this.y[X][Y] == 'B';
   if (boneHere) {
       System.out.printf(............);
   }
   return boneHere;
}
```

Or maybe call it `boneAt`. Your call. If you did not need all that logging, then you can do without the function. But IMHO there is too much repeated code with the logging.